# Logstash extracting and customizing field with grok and ruby

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

i have this data in elastic search logs saved in a `referer` field

```
/clientReq?sessionid=3332&UID=ed91b-517234-4f4c211-a20e-d2e1aefc126a&signUp=false
```

i want to use `ruby` to save this data `ed91b-517234-4f4c211-a20e-d2e1aefc126a` in a separate field.

i have tried this in ruby in my pattern configuration file,

```
ruby {
 code => "
    saveid=event[referer].match((\w+[-]?)+)+)
    event.set('saved',saveid)   "
}
```

this doesn't even save the entire filed. So i went ahead to try `grok` filter instead and tried this,

```
grok {
    match => {"message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    add_field => { "savedData" => "%{referer}" }
}
```

neither of these works. I have tested configuration and if configuring successfully. when i visit kibana front end i don't see new field created either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby hash syntax `event[field] = foo` is not used anymore, and has been replaced by [Get API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html) for example, `event.get(referrer)`.

Beside that, your regex is not correct to get desired results. One of the solutions is to use [Positive Lookbehind](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) to check for **UID**,

this should work,

```
ruby {
 code => "
    saveid = event.get('referer').match(/(?<=UID=)((\w+[-]?)+)+/)[1]
    event.set('saved',saveid)
    "
}
```

for `grok`, you can create a new `filter` for your `referer` field, and use the `gork's` [predefined UUID pattern](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns) to match your string...can you try this,

```
grok {
  match => {"referer" => "UID=%{UUID:saveData}"}
}
```

hope this helps.